# How to convert a Ukrainian driver's license to a US (Massachusetts) license?

Tags: usa, ukraine

A friend of mine has a Ukrainian driver's license. He's moving to study in the US and wants a local one (his stay will be quite lengthy.) What's the best way to do this?

If I understood [this website](https://pilot.mass.gov/how-to/transfer-your-drivers-license-from-a-foreign-country) correctly, then all that is needed is for him to fill out the application correctly and he'll be all set. Is that correct?

Comment: As per your link, the answer is No.  Ukraine is not on the short list of countries whose driver's licenses can be converted to a MA license without tests. He will need to go through some testing procedures and will need to prove residency.

Comment: And further down the appendixA pdf you copied from, it says "A limited number of countries .... without the need for a written or road test."  And the Ukraine is not on that list as per the OPs link.

Comment: @HankyPanky Tom is right - see page 34 and 36 of this document: https://www.massrmv.com/Portals/30/docs/dmanual/chapter_1.pdf

Comment: in which state/region in mexico u can exchange your US license?
seems different states have different laws for this

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you read the website wrong. You are only allowed to convert your licence from a few countries, namely the following ones:

- Canada
- Mexico
- U.S. Territories
- Republic of Korea
- Federal Republic of Germany
- Republic of France
- Taiwan

In case for your Ukranian licence, it is only valid if you have an accompanied [International Driving Permit](https://www.mass.gov/service-details/international-driver-permits) (IDP) with it, and even then it is only valid for one year after you enter the US. You can find the list of countries where you can use an IDP to drive for at most one year [here](http://www.massrmv.com/Portals/30/docs/dmanual/appendix_a.pdf). Ukraine is mentioned on the third page, as one of the post-USSR countries.

If you are staying in the US for longer, you have to apply for a [passenger (Class D) learner's permit](https://www.mass.gov/how-to/apply-for-a-passenger-class-d-learners-permit), and do the appropriate tests to get a full driving licence. Note that you can only apply if you have a valid immigration status for at least 12 months, so it might be possible that your IDP gets invalid before you get a chance of getting a learner's permit.

You can do the driving licence exam in [various languages](http://www.massrmv.com/Portals/30/docs/dmanual/Drivers_Manual.pdf) however. Unfortunately this also doesn't include Ukrainian, only Russian:

- Arabic
- Armenian
- Burmese
- Cambodian (Khmer)
- Chinese (simplified)
- Chinese (traditional)
- English
- Farsi
- French
- German
- Greek
- Gujarati
- Haitian/Creole
- Hindi
- Italian
- Japanese
- Korean
- Laotian
- Polish
- Portuguese (Brazilian)
- Russian
- Serbo-Croatian (Latin)
- Somali
- Spanish
- Tagalog/Filipino
- Thai
- Urdu
- Vietnamese

Comment: An IDP is not required, it is just recommended in case the police have trouble reading the actual license ([see Appendix A](https://pilot.mass.gov/files/2017-06/Valid%20Foreign%20Licenses.pdf)). Also in Massachusetts "converting your license" means giving up your current license for one of their's, which people with a license from any Appendix A country can do. Only people from the short list of countries  can avoid the tests when converting but I believe the others can at least avoid having to have a already-licensed "sponsor" to accompany them for their driving test.

Comment: IDP is recommended if the licence is not in English, which is most likely true for an Ukrainian one

Comment: I am pretty sure that the 12 month statement, which says it's _from_ the application date, is to ensure that the applicant is here on a long-stay visa, not a short-term visitor's visa.

Comment: @mkennedy with Real ID licenses, states are required to verify the actual immigration status of license applicants.  The 12-month limitation seems more about limiting bureaucratic workload than anything else.  The US sometimes admits visitors for 12 months, and sometimes admits non-visitors for shorter periods, or indefinitely ("duration of status," or D/S).  In some states, people admitted indefinitely can only get a license valid for one year.

Comment: Looking at this again, it seems that you may be misinterpreting "valid immigration status for at least 12 months": it doesn't mean that you have to wait 12 months before applying but rather that your period of admission must be 12 months or longer.  You can apply as soon as you become a Massachusetts resident.  (Furthermore, that requirement does not apply to "standard" licenses, only to Real ID licenses; see https://www.mass.gov/guides/massachusetts-identification-id-requirements .)

Comment: @phoog, All Real ID licenses issued to non-immigrants with indefinite stays (except citizens of the Freely Associated States) are only valid for one year. That restriction comes from the federal Real ID regulations, so all states (should) do it that way.

Comment: @Dennis I'm well aware of that, since my wife was such a nonimmigrant for some 23 years (since long before Real ID came into being).  This is precisely why someone admitted for duration of status would be likely to choose a "standard" license in Massachusetts or the analogous license in those states that offer one (not all do).

Comment: @SztupY Ukrainian driver licenses are both in Ukrainian and English, so IDP is not needed for the first 3 months if I understand that correctly.